# Multi Threading FileSystemWatcher monitor local folder changed and timer to handle when network is down and Ping again in Window Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, filesystemwatcher

By default a Script written by the machine saves the files to Local/Server Path folder, but due to network issue, both the folders are not in sync. I have witten a C# Window Service program using FileSystemWatcher, DiffEngine, System.Timers and PingService as below coding to handle this.
To monitor a local folder OnChange Event, Ping server IP whether is success/fail before Compare/Copy to Server path,  When Ping Fail it will goes to logtemp folder, system timer handle this and Ping again before re-dump the logtemp files.

I do not know how to use threading for this. Where should be my system timer code when the ping fails?

```cs
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{  //all watcher config here// 
    watcher.Path = "path";
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
    watcher.Filter = "filename_company-Pg1_Product*";
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(LogFileSystemChanges);
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;}

private void LogFileSystemChanges(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{ 
    FileInfo sourcepath = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
    FileInfo destPath = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(dFile, e.Name));
    FileInfo _tempPath = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(tempPath, e.Name));

    if (PingService()) 
    //PingService Bool Type....Ping Specific IP Before Compare/Copy
    {
       if (!destPath.Exists) 
       {
          LogEvent(destPath + " DOES NOT EXIST!! ");
          CopyFunction.CopyFile(sourcepath, destPath, true, true);
       }
       else
       {
          if (BinaryDiff(sFile, Path.Combine(dFile, e.Name))) 
          //DiffEngine If Source & Diff are Different is TRUE.
          {
             CopyFunction.CopyFile(sourcepath, destPath, true, true);
          }
       }
       string msg = string.Format("Filename {0} are {1} now at {2} ", _
                    e.Name, e.ChangeType, DateTime.Now.ToString());
       LogEvent(msg);
       }
       else
       {
           CopyFunction.CopyFile(sourcepath, _tempPath, true, true);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NServiceBus (with what they call a Saga)

Its an open source project that lets you foolproof your code against cases where the network is down.

Or are you just asking how to make a thread?

If so see [MSDN on examples for creating threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#vcwlkthreadingtutorialexample1creating)